# Bind data to a dataGrid from inside a event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

I have a function that has a string with information, splits it up and then adds rows and columns to a asp.net GridView.

That is fine, but the problem is that this function is fired from an event, and then when i do :

```
TestGrid.DataSource = (myTable).DefaultView;
TestGrid.DataBind();
```

It doesnt fill the grid and display (the myTable has all the correct information)

My grid looks like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateTestingGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="TestGrid" runat="server" CssClass="pipesTbl">

                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
```

And if i understand correctly it is something to do with that it is out of the context,

Can any one try and help with this? **even to just help me with were and what to start searching google**? what am i looking for?

**EDIT**

Hope this helps a bit

```
protected void progressBar_RunTask(object sender, EO.Web.ProgressTaskEventArgs e)
{       
    tester.done += new tester.PipeDoneEvtArgs(tester_Done);

    progressBar.Maximum = 100;

}

void tester_Done(double runTime)
{

    DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

    //Here i fill the myTable with rows and columns

    TestGrid.DataSource = (myTable).DefaultView;
    TestGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Which control fire the event where you bind data to GridView?

Comment: Which event you are handling to populate the "myTable" and binding a GridView?

Comment: @AVD, Thanks i edited the question for more code...

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke Update() method of UpdatePanel in order to refresh the child controls (GridView).

```
void tester_Done(double runTime)
{
    DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

    //Here i fill the myTable with rows and columns

    TestGrid.DataSource = (myTable).DefaultView;
    TestGrid.DataBind();
    UpdateTestingGrid.Update(); // UpdateMode must be Conditional
 }
```

Comment: I did that but it didnt help... any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Please edit you question to reflect that question related to essentialobjects library.

Also did you saw this Demo? [Demo link](http://demo.essentialobjects.com/Demos/Progress%20Bar/Server%20Side%20Task%20-%20Advanced%201/Demo.aspx)

I believe that you may add hidden button into UpdateTestingGrid update panel and call __doPostBack method for this button in ClientSideOnTaskDone method of progressbar.
Perform gridview databinding in click event handler of that button.

Comment: Thank you! can you show me with code exactly what you mean? I am new to c#